# Determine what user 'ms access database' is using to link to another database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

When trying to import a table onto a ms-access database from another database, I get the error

```
You don't have permission to import, export, or link to 'exampleTbl.'
To import, export, or link to this object, you must have Read Design and Read Data permissions for it.
```

I checked the database I am importing from and my computers username has the ability to read and write to this database.

So I was thinking that maybe the access database I am trying to import to is using a different username to grab the data.

In short how do I found out what username is being used when attempting to import a table onto a ms access database.

Importing from a ms-access database. external data -> access -> browse to db -> Open -> Import Tables checked -> OK -> select table -> desired table click ok -> then error shows up.

Comment: (1) What is the source database from which you are trying to import? ...Microsoft SQL Server? ...something else? (2) Please confirm the exact steps you are using to attempt the import, e.g., from the Access ribbon via `External Data > Import & Link > ODBC Database`...?

Comment: added the info you wanted

Comment: yes windows user @HansUp

Comment: Forget about import for the moment.  Can you open that other db file directly in Access?  If so, can you open the `exampleTbl` table in Datasheet View?  Can you open it in Design View?

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if this is an .mdb database with User-Level security enabled. Do you need to enter any sort of password to open the source database (the one with the table you're trying to import)?